# Have a c# program close

Tags: c#

In my program, I need to have the program close if bool option = false. The "while (option == false)" statement is at the bottom of the code. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double numA = 0;
        double numB = 0;
        double answer = 0;
        string functionType;
        string aLine;
        string bLine;
        string next;
        bool option = true;

        while (option == true)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a function type: ");
            functionType = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (functionType)
            {

                case "V":
                    Console.WriteLine(" +   Addition" + '\n' + " -   Subtraction" + '\n'                + " *   Multiplication" + '\n' + " /   Division" + '\n' + " %   Percent" + '\n' + " \\   Square Root" + '\n' + " ^   Exponent");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a function type: ");
                    functionType = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;

                case "v":
                    Console.WriteLine(" +   Addition" + '\n' + " -   Subtraction" + '\n' + " *   Multiplication" + '\n' + " /   Division" + '\n' + " %   Percent" + '\n' + " \\   Square Root" + '\n' + " ^   Exponent");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a function type: ");
                    functionType = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number: ");
            aLine = Console.ReadLine();
            numA = Double.Parse(aLine); Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number: ");

            switch (functionType)
            {

                case "\\":
                    answer = Math.Sqrt(numA);
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + answer + '\n');

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to do more calculations? (Y/N): ");
            next = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (next)
            {
                case "Y":
                    option = true;
                    Console.WriteLine('\n');
                    break;

                case "y":
                    option = true;
                    Console.WriteLine('\n');
                    break;

                case "N":
                    option = false;
                    break;

                case "n":
                    option = false;
                    break;

            }
            continue;
                    break;

                case "%":
                    answer = numA * 100;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + answer + '\n');

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to do more calculations? (Y/N): ");
            next = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (next)
            {
                case "Y":
                    option = true;
                    Console.WriteLine('\n');
                    break;

                case "y":
                    option = true;
                    Console.WriteLine('\n');
                    break;

                case "N":
                    option = false;
                    break;

                case "n":
                    option = false;
                    break;

            }
                    break;
                    continue;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number: ");
            bLine = Console.ReadLine();
            numB = Double.Parse(bLine);

            switch (functionType)
            {

                case "+":
                    answer = numA + numB;
                    break;

                case "-":
                    answer = numA - numB;
                    break;

                case "x":
                    answer = numA * numB;
                    break;


                case "*":
                    answer = numA * numB;
                    break;


                case "X":
                    answer = numA * numB;
                    break;

                case "/":
                    answer = numA / numB;
                    break;

                case "^":
                    answer = Math.Pow(numA, numB);
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + answer + '\n');

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to do more calculations? (Y/N): ");
            next = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (next)
            {
                case "Y":
                    option = true;
                    Console.WriteLine('\n');
                    break;

                case "y":
                    option = true;
                    Console.WriteLine('\n');
                    break;

                case "N":
                    option = false;
                    break;

                case "n":
                    option = false;
                    break;

            }


        }

        while (option == false)
        {

        }

    }
}
}
```

Forgive me if this is an easy answer, but I have been learning c# for about 2 hours.

Comment: Yes, but only answers about c and c++ show up.

Comment: I don't understand anything.Do you want to do something inside of your last while loop? if you want to close the program then delete that while loop and it will close

Comment: It's a console app, just get rid of your `while(option == false)` and it should close automatically because you are no longer in Main which is what is keeping your program alive.

Comment: @user3259479 this is actually more or less the same in C and C++ and is very basic.

Comment: remove the loop at the bottom and change the main loop to `while (option)` and when it becomes false it should exit by itself at the end. You should also rework all your switches and calculation as they can be all fit into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `while (option == false)` loop at the end.  What you do need to do, is check the value after each user input, and only proceed if the condition is not met.  Ie, after each switch statement:

```
if (!option)
    return;
```

This will exit from the outer while loop, and then the `Main` function will exit, thus ending your program.